# How to use floating bottom navigation bar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-pub, flutter-bottomnavigation

I'm trying to use this plugin called Dot navigation bar (https://pub.dev/packages/dot_navigation_bar) and I already installed the plugin into my current project but I'm just wondering how can I pass my existing Screens.

I have Home(), Calender(), Help(), Schedule() screen so just wondering how can I open those page when I click on the icons. Any help or suggestion will be really appreciated.

This is the example code from the documentation.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  var _selectedTab = _SelectedTab.home;

  void _handleIndexChanged(int i) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedTab = _SelectedTab.values[i];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      body: Container(
        child: Image.asset("lib/img/1.png"),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
        child: DotNavigationBar(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
          currentIndex: _SelectedTab.values.indexOf(_selectedTab),
          dotIndicatorColor: Colors.white,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey[300],
          // enableFloatingNavBar: false,
          onTap: _handleIndexChanged,
          items: [
            /// Home
            DotNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              selectedColor: Color(0xff73544C),
            ),

            /// Likes
            DotNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
              selectedColor: Color(0xff73544C),
            ),

            /// Search
            DotNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              selectedColor: Color(0xff73544C),
            ),

            /// Profile
            DotNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              selectedColor: Color(0xff73544C),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

enum _SelectedTab { home, favorite, search, person }
```

Right now It just showing like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can replace this package and feed any (custom/ default flutter NavigationBar) in the **floatingActionButton** parameter of the main Scaffold as shown below

```
Scaffold(
    extendBody: true,  // <--- do not forget mark this as true
    floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    floatingActionButton: NavigationBar(...),
    ...
)
```

as described in this thread, kudos to @Iman

[Custom floating bottom navigation bar has white background flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72553177/custom-floating-bottom-navigation-bar-has-white-background-flutter)

```
Scaffold(
    extendBody: true, // <--- do not forget mark this as true
    floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    floatingActionButton: Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
      ),
      child: NavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, // <--- to remove background color
        elevation: 0,                       // <--- to remove shadows
        ....
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

In `body` pass array of `navigation` items.

In addition, you would need to add `.index` because `_selectedTab` is not an int value.

```
navigation=[home(), favorite(), search(), person()]
body: navigation[_selectedTab.index]
```